# How to set a node attribute with serverspec

Tags: chef-infra, serverspec

I'm pretty new to serverspec. I have a recipe which uses something along the lines of the following:

```
c = node['a']['b']
```

My question is, in the actual test, how could i set that value?

Comment: That code works as is in Serverspec. Is there something unusual that would prevent it from working?

Comment: That's a great question. I know it works when I just execute it via chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Serverspec is unrelated to Chef and doesn't know anything about node attributes. It has its own very limited version of ohai, so you can see the platform name and version and that's about it.